# Was Savitri avatar of some goddess?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas

Savitri story is quite popular where she made Yama return life of her husband.

Was Savitri avatar of some deity ? Or was she a normal woman ?

Answer (score -1):

**Srimad Devi Bhagwatam.:**

**Book 9. Chapter 27 - On the birth, etc., of Sāvitrī.:**

> *O King! I know your desire. Certainly I will give what you and your wife long for. Your chaste wife is anxious for a daughter, while you want a son. So, one after another, the desires of both of you will be fulfilled.” Thus saying, the Devī went to the Brahma Loka. The King also returned to his house. First a daughter was born to him. As the daughter was born, as if a second Lakṣmī was born after worshipping Sāvitrī, the King kept her name as Sāvitrī.*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..